# Fetch start and end between two dates inclusive in pyspark

Tags: date, datetime, pyspark, explode

I have been trying to fetch months range from 2 given dates, but it's not working as expected.

e.g.

- start_date (dd-mm-yyyy) = 12-01-2022
- end_date (dd-mm-yyyy) = 03-06-2022

Expected output:

| Valid_From | Valid_To |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-31 |
| 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-03 |

My code:

```py
var_forecast_start_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12)
var_forecast_end_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2)

df_datetime = pandas_to_spark(
    df_datetime(start=var_forecast_start_date, end=var_forecast_end_date)
)


df_datetime = df_datetime.withColumn(
    "DateID", date_format(df_datetime.Date, "yyyyMMdd").cast(IntegerType())
).withColumn("FiscalDate", date_format(df_datetime.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd"))

df_datetime = df_datetime.selectExpr(
    "add_months(date_add(last_day(Date),1),-1) AS Valid_From",
    "last_day(Date) AS Valid_To",
).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try maybe the following:

```py
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

findspark.init()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local").getOrCreate()
columns = ["start_date", "end_date"]
data = [("12-01-2022", "03-06-2022")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "start_date", F.to_date(F.col("start_date"), "dd-MM-yyyy").cast("DATE")
    )
    .withColumn(
        "end_date", F.to_date(F.col("end_date"), "dd-MM-yyyy").cast("DATE")
    )
    .withColumn(
        "months_between",
        F.round(
            F.months_between(F.col("end_date"), F.col("start_date"), True)
        ).cast("Integer"),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "months_between_seq", F.sequence(F.lit(1), F.col("months_between"))
    )
    .withColumn("months_between_seq", F.explode(F.col("months_between_seq")))
    .withColumn(
        "end_of_month",
        F.expr(
            """
                LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, months_between_seq - 1))
            """
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "begin_of_month",
        F.expr(
            """
                LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, months_between_seq - 1)) + 1
            """
        ),
    )
)

start_window_agg = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("Valid_From")
start_union_sdf = (
    df.select(
        F.col("start_date").alias("Valid_From")
    )
    .unionByName(
        df.select(
            F.col("begin_of_month").alias("Valid_From")
        )
    )
    .drop_duplicates()
    .withColumn(
        "row_number",
        F.row_number().over(start_window_agg)
    )
)
end_window_agg = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("Valid_To")
end_union_sdf = (
    df.select(
        F.col("end_date").alias("Valid_To")
    )
    .unionByName(
        df.select(
            F.col("end_of_month").alias("Valid_To")
        )
    )
    .drop_duplicates()
    .withColumn(
        "row_number",
        F.row_number().over(end_window_agg)
    )
)
join_sdf = (
    end_union_sdf
    .join(
        start_union_sdf,
        how="inner",
        on=["row_number"]
    )
    .drop("row_number")
    .withColumn("Valid_To", F.col("Valid_To").cast("DATE"))
    .withColumn("Valid_From", F.col("Valid_From").cast("DATE"))
    .select("Valid_From", "Valid_To")
    .orderBy("Valid_From")
)
join_sdf.show()
```

It returns:

```
+----------+----------+
|Valid_From|  Valid_To|
+----------+----------+
|2022-01-12|2022-01-31|
|2022-02-01|2022-02-28|
|2022-03-01|2022-03-31|
|2022-04-01|2022-04-30|
|2022-05-01|2022-05-31|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. The output really seems close by to my requirement. By Any chance will we be able to fetch the dates in 2 columns?

Comment: date1from_start date1from_end Diff
4/15/2022          4/30/2022         16
5/1/2022                  5/31/2022         31
6/1/2022                  6/30/2022         30
7/1/2022                  7/22/2022         22

Comment: @LuffyRaj, I implemented the changes. Please use proper markdown next time as your question was quite unclear due to it's bad formatting. Here is a link for how to do that. *[Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org)*

Comment: @LuffyRaj, is the answer I provided correct? If so can you please mark the question as complete or correct.

Comment: thank you for the logic, this is exactly the dates that I was looking for.
I have a dataframe, with two date columns as we take them as input to the above code u shared, will we be able to join this with the same dataframe along with other columns?

Comment: `df.selectExpr("tactic", "GTIN", "soldto","date1from", "date1to", "sequence(to_date(date1from), to_date(date1to), interval 1 month) as date") \
.withColumn("date", explode(col("date"))) \
.withColumn("lastdate1", last_day(col("date"))) \
.withColumn("startdate", greatest( "date1from", trunc( col("lastdate1"),"month") ) ) \
.withColumn("lastdate", least(df.date1to, "lastdate1")) \
.withColumn("datediff", datediff("lastdate", "startdate") +1) \
.select("tactic", "GTIN", "soldto","date1from", "date1to", "startdate", "lastdate", "datediff" ) \
.display()`